# Why do I keep getting errors in this piece of code for Standard ML?

Tags: sml, ml

I am learning standard ML and I keep getting this error and I am not sure why?

Here is the code and the error:

```
> fun in_list(element, list) = 
    if hd(list) = element then true
    else val tempList = List.drop(list, 1);
    in_list(element, tempList);
# # Error-Expression expected but val was found
Static Errors
```

I know there has to be something wrong with the syntax that I am trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap `val` values in a `let..in..end` block.

```
fun in_list(element, list) = 
    if hd(list) = element then true
    else 
        let
           val tempList = List.drop(list, 1)
        in
           in_list(element, tempList)
        end
```

Moreover, `hd` and `drop` aren't recommended to decompose a list. You should use pattern-matching instead.

```
fun in_list(element, x::xs) = 
    if x = element then true
    else in_list(element, xs)
```

There is a base case with empty list missing, and you can use `orelse`to replace `if x = element then true ...`. I leave them for you as suggestions.

Comment: Oh cool,  what does the x::xs do? i know that "::" means cons. also how to can i get it to return false?

Comment: `::` is cons constructor which is used to break down a non-empty list to the head `x` and the tail `xs`. A list is constructed using empty list `[]` and `::`. For example, `[1, 2, 3]` actually is `1::2::3::[]`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, How can i get the function to return false if it is not true, because we used the "then" keyword to return the true cases.

Comment: Well, as I said in my answer, you missed a base case `fun in_list(element, []) = false | in_list(element, x::xs) = ...`. You simply return `false` if the input list is empty.